# Converting null literal for Console.ReadLine() for string input

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I am new to c# so i need some guidance with this.

```
string NumInput = Console.ReadLine();
```

in my code, this statement gives the warning of

converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.

Is there any alternative to this code line or anything which can make this warning disapear

Comment: Change `string` to `string?` or `var`.

Comment: Or add `#nullable disable` to the file.

Comment: Or use: `string NumInput = Console.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;`

Comment: For reference and further study, you are getting this error because you have nullable reference types enabled in your project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references. `Console.ReadLine` returns a nullable string (`string?`) which you are trying to assign to a non-nullable string variable.

Comment: For completeness, `Console.ReadLine()` can return `null` if standard input has been redirected. For example, your application could be invoked as `myapp < input.txt`; if `input.txt` is empty `NumInput` would end up as `null`, and if nullable references are enabled you would be expected to handle this case. When used interactively, it will never return `null` since the application won't proceed until the user has entered a line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly, you are seeing this message because you have the C# 8 [Nullable reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) feature enabled in your project.
`Console.ReadLine()` returns a value that can be either a **string** or **null** but you are using it to set a variable of type **string**. Instead either use the `var` keyword which will implicitly set your variable to the same type as the return value or manually set your variable as type **nullable string**  `string?`. the `?` denotes a nullable reference type.

You may then want to check that your variable does infact hold a string before you use it:

```
string? NumInput = Console.ReadLine();
if (NumInput == null)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: While your explanation is sound, the proposed code is not. `Console.ReadLine()` will only return `null` if the end of input has been reached for redirected input, and if it has, reading it again will simply get you `null` again, so this becomes an infinite loop. In an interactive setup, if the user enters nothing (simply presses Enter), it will return an empty string, not `null`. Therefore, just repeating the operation never makes sense.

Comment: @JeroenMostert ahh right! Thanks for the explanation. I'll adjust my answer to remove that part. It's unrelated to the question anyway.

Comment: Can you explain why they felt the need to make the return type for Console.ReadLine() "string?" ?   When string itself can be null, isn't "string?" redundant ?

Comment: @paneerlovr Take a look at the link I posted in my answer regarding Nullable reference types, this is new feature in C# 8 that you can enable. Basically, treat nullable reference types in a similar manner to nullable value types, so maybe-null reference type should use the "?" to specify that it is potentially null. 
Any reference types without the "?" are treated as not nullable.

Comment: With pattern matching you can take a shortcut. E.g.,: `if(Console.ReadLine() is string numInput) { ... }`.

Comment: To add to what Oliver said: `if (Console.ReadLine() is string input && input == "yes") { ... }`