# Why is this problem arising with my code?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I am learning C# with the help of the Brackeys tutorial and while taking a string variable I got this problem:

```
Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
```

My code is

```
using System;

namespace All_Projects
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");

            string userName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Hello " + userName + ", nice to meet you");
            
            //Wait before closing
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I am using VS Code 2019 and .NET 6.0.1

Comment: Most likely you have nullable reference types enabled, and `Console.ReadLine()` is declared as returning `string?`, which can be `null`. Your code, however, stores it in `string`, which should not be `null`. Just try `string? userName = ...`. `null` will occur if you have redirected the input to this program and there is no input left to consume.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen FYI net6 has nullable ref types on by default now

Comment: Give your question a proper title.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting null literal for Console.ReadLine() for string input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70291276/converting-null-literal-for-console-readline-for-string-input)

Answer (score 0):

The problem (which should be a warning, not an error) here is originating from the line
`string userName = Console.ReadLine();` because `Console.ReadLine` [return string?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=net-6.0) which is a string that's nullable aware (more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types))

Now to fix your problem you have several ways.

the first one would be to forgive the null using (null-forgiving operator), which is used to declare that a value is not null.
`string userName = Console.ReadLine()!;` (note the ! operator before the ;)

or you can make `userName` nullable string and check if it has a value to continue the program otherwise quit (or any other logic you want).

```
Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");

string? userName = Console.ReadLine();
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName)) return; //exiting

Console.WriteLine("Hello " + userName! + ", nice to meet you");
            
//Wait before closing
Console.ReadKey();
```

If you are starting with C#, nullability is a bit of mid-level topic. I suggest you disable it if you are annoyed (remove enabled) from your .csproj or add #nullable disable on top of your file.