# CS8600 Error while using the ReadLine() command

Tags: c#, console.readline

CS8600 Error while using the `ReadLine()` command;

Code:

```
namespace Something{
 
    class UserInputEg{

        static void Main(string[] args){

            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(input);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
> line 7

[Screenshot of the code and the warning associated with it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5JJR.png)

Comment: It’s a warning, not an error. You can turn the nullability warnings off if you want, or mark the variable correctly as nullable.

Comment: try this.. string? input = Console.ReadLine(); https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70291276/converting-null-literal-for-console-readline-for-string-input