# How do I prevent the "Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type." error?

Tags: c#, user-input

Each time I keep on trying to do `Console.ReadLine` in VS Code, it gives me this error:

> Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.

For context, this is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calc v0.1");

        Console.WriteLine("Enter:");

        string num1 = Console.ReadLine();
        string num2 = Console.ReadLine();

        //I realize that it won't actually add the numbers; I'm just trying to at least get some type of    output from the program.
        Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
    }
}
```

I was expecting the program to ask for user input but it keeps on giving me the error above.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70294197/16606026) solve your question?

Comment: Change `string x = Console.ReadLine()` to `string x = Console.ReadLine() ?? "";`

Comment: `string? num1 =...`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a duplicate, but you need to tell C# that it's ok for your `string` variables to accept a `ReadLine` return of `null` (which it will do if there is nothing in the input stream). One simple way is to use the null-forgiving operator `!` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving).

Dai and Charlieface have suggested alternatives that are variations on this theme.

This compiles without error or warning (.NET 6) and runs without issue:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calc v0.1");

        Console.WriteLine("Enter:");

        string num1 = Console.ReadLine()!; // null-forgiveness
        string? num2 = Console.ReadLine(); // declare num2 as nullable
        string num3 = Console.ReadLine()??""; // check if ReadLine returns null and return empty string instead

        Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2 + num3);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Calc v0.1
Enter:
la
ti
da
latida
```

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS8600)#possible-null-assigned-to-a-nonnullable-reference

Comment: Thanks for the response, in the website you linked it said all I had to do was to add a "!" after the Console.ReadLines() as a null-forgiving operator. However, when I run the code, it doesn't print the user input; It just completely stops after the "Console.WriteLine("Enter:")"

Comment: Define "completely stops". Does it throw an exception? Does it hang? If it's hanging, are you entering something on the console and pressing `<Enter>`?

Comment: Dai's comment is another good option. You can also adjust the severity level of the warnings/errors but I would not recommend doing that.